# function returning opposite boolean value to what I expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this function in my `.tsx` file:

```js
doIsChecked() {
    var isItChecked = document.getElementById('isPless') as HTMLInputElement;

    console.log('updateDocsFlag before: ' + this.state.updateDocsFlag);
    if (isItChecked.checked) {
        this.setState({ updateDocsFlag: true });
    } else {
        this.setState({ updateDocsFlag: false });
    }
    console.log('updateDocsFlag after: ' + this.state.updateDocsFlag);
}
```

It get called when a checkbox is ticked/unticked. I noticed that if `isItChecked` is true `updateDocsFlag` is false as can be seen in the before and after log entries. This isn't the behaviour I expected Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Check what value in `isItChecked.checked` when you click a checkbox two times

Comment: When I click it twice the value of `isItChecked.checked` is `false`. The checkbox is unchecked on screen.

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example on jsfiddle or a similar service?

Comment: Will take a look.

Comment: how about moving your console.log in the second parameter of `this.setState` like this `this.setState({ updateDocsFlag: true }, ()=> console.log('updateDocsFlag after: ' + this.state.updateDocsFlag););`

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState` is asynchronius. it does set the right state,but not at the moment of the call. so when you call

```
    console.log('updateDocsFlag after: ' + this.state.updateDocsFlag);
```

you still see the old state.
try to do following:

```
doIsChecked() {
    var isItChecked = document.getElementById('isPless') as HTMLInputElement;

    console.log('updateDocsFlag before: ' + this.state.updateDocsFlag);
    let updateDocsFlag = isItChecked.checked;
    this.setState({ updateDocsFlag });
    console.log('updateDocsFlag after: ' + updateDocsFlag);
}
```

this way you log not the state, but the value you passing into the state. You suppose to see there the right value. (and the actual state will update with this value after all active functions traces will end)